# How to split huge array into small array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have huge array and need to split it into small array so that I can run it faster.
I have array look like this:

```
var callUrls = ['url1','url2','url3','url4','url5','url6','url7','url8','url9','url10'];
```

And I want to split it like this:

```
var callUrls = [
    [url1, url2, url3, url4, url5],
    [url6, url7, url8, url9, url10]
];
```

How can I do that in js? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would it run faster if it was split? What do you want to do?

Comment: What is the use case where you are assuming that a giant array of arrays will be "faster" than a giant array? I would re-evaluate that assumption before you go through the trouble.

Comment: @SergeyBelyakov javascript

Comment: You haven't given a use case for this. On what condition are you splitting this array? Half? Specific index value? We need more information, as this question is too broad.

Comment: @SergeyBelyakov `array_chunk` in JavaScript??

Comment: you can declare this function and use
http://javascript.ru/php/array_chunk

Comment: I have 10000 urls and need to run to grab data from that urls, I use async.eachSeries but it run 1 url at a time. So I think I should split that huge array into small array and run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
var callUrls = ['url1','url2','url3','url4','url5','url6','url7','url8','url9','url10'];
var n=5;
var temp=[];
for(var i=0;i<callUrls.length;i+=n)
  temp.push(callUrls.slice(i,i+n));
console.log(temp);
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/54an2z05/)**</kbd>